# Node.js with A2 Hosting Error 404 when loading mydomain.com/anyotherpage

Tags: node.js, express

I have followed the steps on A2's tutorial for "Cannot GET" URL here:
https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/cpanel/cpanel-software/node-js-application-error-message-cannot-get-url

The main page, mydomain.com, loads fine and the CSS loads as well but
when I try to go anywhere else, like mydomain.com/port or mydomain.com/anythingelse, I get a 404 error (pic below).

The ejs and CSS templates are in the same file location, and if I change the "/" route to the other page's .ejs/.css that loads just fine so it is finding those routes, but for some reason no other URL routes besides "/" load.

mydomain.com - loads perfectly fine

mydomain.com/anythingelse - the 404 error

This is my app.js:

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const path = require("path")

const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"))
app.set("view engine", "ejs")

app.use("/test1/static", express.static("public/"))

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("home-visitor")
})

app.get("/port", function (req, res) {
  res.render("port")
})

app.listen()
```

[I have kept my Applicaiton URL blank on purpose so I have a clean home page address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNNtO.png)

[I have tried using a non-blank Application URL and change the app.js file to match syntax accordingly with no difference in outcome (tried '/test/port/', '/test/port', 'test/port/', 'test/port'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjTFS.png)

[This is what I find in the console under Network>post>Headers when I try to load the page on mydomain.com/port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC5TR.png)

Thanks for any help, I am still new to node.js being hosted with A2 Hosting so I am hoping I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.JS you have

```
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"))
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
```

That means that if you do something like
`res.render(“port”)`

inside of your views folder you need to have a port.ejs file

Take a look at one of my old repos
https://github.com/EnetoJara/KardexDL/tree/master/views/template

The code is a lil bit out of date but you can get some ideas

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear on that, the route for "/" works, but the route for "/port" does not and that is what I am stumped on.

Comment: so no other routes besides "/" will work at this point even if the route is properly added in app.js

Comment: The problem might be on the res.render() app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"))
app.set("view engine", "ejs")

Comment: I do have a port.ejs file, it is in the "views" folder along with the home-visitor.ejs and all of the other .ejs templates. That is what I am so confused about. So if I do, for example:

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("port")
})

the "/" path will show the port.ejs. page or any other .ejs file in that same folder without issue. 

The issue occurs when I try to load: mydomain.com/literallyanyotherURLname and I get the 404 error I attached up above

Comment: I hope that makes sense

Comment: It's as if A2 Hosting is unable to process any other app.get request other than the "/" URL route

Comment: I am guessing it has something to do with how A2 uses Phusion Passenger, if I upload the same project to Heroku I have no issues.